# Move Google Maps Static API attribution to top right

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

Is there any API parameter that lets me move the copyright attribution that's currently appearing on the lower right of a static map image generated by Google Maps Static API to the upper right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such parameter in Google Maps APIs. In addition it is prohibited to modify attribution, you should display it as provided by Google.

Have a look at Terms of Service of Google Maps Platform. Paragraph 3.2.3 (b) reads:

> *Attribution*.  Customer will display all attribution that (i) Google provides through the Services (including branding, logos, and copyright and trademark notices); or (ii) is specified in the Service Specific Terms. Customer **will not modify, obscure, or delete** such attribution.

source: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3-license

I hope this clarifies your doubt.

Comment: Yes, that's why I wanted to move it. I need to overlay something on top of the image and I don't want to obscure the attribution.